# Javascript dom tree modification

Tags: javascript, dom, tree, innerhtml, appendchild

Whats the wayto  modify the "body" of a dom tree like this using javascript:

```
Original htm:    <html> <head></head>   <body>  blah blah blah  </body>  </html>

Modified html:    <html>  <head> </head>  <abc> <body> blah blah blad </body> </abc> </html>
```

That is, I wish to put the whole **body** node inside another node.

The code I am trying is:

*// Create an iframe*

var orig_iframe = document.createElement('iframe');

*// Copy body's content inside iframe (hopefully!)*

orig_iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML;

*// Set document body to null*

document.body.innerHTML = '';

*// Add iframe to body*

document.body.appendChild(orig_iframe);

which doesnt work. Obviously I am missing something!

Thanks!

Comment: What happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: I wouldn't try this. You are trying to generate a DOM that doesn't conform to the HTML specification. Browsers perform some levels of error recovery and sometimes outright reject changes that attempt to violate the spec.

Comment: Do you want to wrap a <tag> in the <body> element?

Comment: @David: Sorry, I am sort of beginner and dont understand exactly what you mean.

@ Gerard:  Yes.   Basically, I want to generate  <body> <iframe> original body contents </iframe> </body>

Comment: @David:  btw, abc was just for example. I will use proper html tag (in my case, iframe) ...if thats what you mentioned as concern.

Comment: I think David's complaining about putting the `<body>` *inside* another element, which doesn't make any sense. I think you really want to put the *contents* of the body inside another element, not the body itself. However, this makes no sense for `iframe` anyway, since the contents of an `<iframe>` tag aren't displayed (it's backup for non-frame browsers, which don't really exist any more). You seem to want to move the contents of `<body>` to a completely new document, the one displayed by the iframe.

Comment: Oh, Bobince, thats correct! The original post is a typo. I do want <body> <abc> .... </abc> </body>. Second, I completely forgot about the iframe syntax! (dont dabble with html so often!). So will tell you what I basically want to achieve.... I essentially want to split the page into 2 (thought iframe is the right way to do it) and display original page in one iframe and some other content in the other.... Can you suggest some way? thanks

Answer (score 1):

> orig_iframe.contentDocument.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML;

There's no `innerHTML` property on `HTMLDocument`, only on `HTMLElement`. You'd probably want to set `innerHTML` on the iframe document's `body` element.

However, writing `iframe`​s dynamically has some browser wrinkles.

```
var html= document.body.innerHTML;
var iframe= document.createElement('iframe');
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var idoc= 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
idoc.write('<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html><head></head><body></body></html>');
idoc.close();
idoc.body.innerHTML= html;
```

The business with `contentWindow` is necessary for IE up to version 7, which do not support the standard property `contentDocument`.

The `write()` call is to ensure that a minimal document is present in the `iframe` so that you can then set `innerHTML` on its body. The `<!DOCTYPE` declaration in it is required to put that window into Standards Mode (which is hopefully what you're using on the main document too).

Whilst you *could* `document.write` the HTML content to the new document, that would cause any `<script>` elements inside the body to execute again in the new document, which you probably don't want. Writing to `innerHTML` avoids immediate execution of any scripts in the string.